# Como evitar erro de data inválida em uma subconsulta

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

No código abaixo, a subconsulta "D" retorna apenas datas válidas na coluna DIA, no entanto, ao tentar filtrar essa coluna usando a cláusula WHERE, o Oracle exibe a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> "ORA-01839: a data não é válida para o mês especificado"

Como faço para filtrar essa coluna na cláusula WHERE sem que esse erro apareça?

**Exemplo do código sem WHERE e sem o erro:**

```
SELECT 
   D.DIA,
   D.MES_ANO,
   D.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(C.DIA),2,'0') || '/' || C.MES_ANO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') DIA,
      C.MES_ANO,
      C.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
   FROM
      (
      SELECT
        B.DIA,
         A.MES_ANO,
         A.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
      FROM
         (
            SELECT '04/2018' MES_ANO, TO_DATE('30/04/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '05/2018' MES_ANO, TO_DATE('31/05/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '06/2018' MES_ANO, TO_DATE('30/06/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL 
         ) A,
         ( SELECT ROWNUM DIA FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31 ) B 
      WHERE
         B.DIA <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(A.ULTIMO_DIA_MES, 'DD'))
      ) C
   ) D 
ORDER BY 
   D.DIA;
```

**Exemplo do código com WHERE e com o erro:**

```
SELECT 
   D.DIA,
   D.MES_ANO,
   D.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      TO_DATE(LPAD(TO_CHAR(C.DIA),2,'0') || '/' || C.MES_ANO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') DIA,
      C.MES_ANO,
      C.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
   FROM
      (
      SELECT
        B.DIA,
         A.MES_ANO,
         A.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
      FROM
         (
            SELECT '04/2018' MES_ANO, TO_DATE('30/04/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '05/2018' MES_ANO, TO_DATE('31/05/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '06/2018' MES_ANO, TO_DATE('30/06/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL 
         ) A,
         ( SELECT ROWNUM DIA FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31 ) B 
      WHERE
         B.DIA <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(A.ULTIMO_DIA_MES, 'DD'))
      ) C
   ) D   
WHERE 
   D.DIA < SYSDATE
ORDER BY 
   D.DIA;
```

Comment: tente com SELECT  lpad(ROWNUM,2,'0') dia FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31

Comment: Mesmo usando o LPAD no ROWNUM, o erro continua acontecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT D.DIA, D.MES_ANO, D.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
FROM
   (SELECT
      CASE WHEN C.DIA < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END || TO_CHAR(C.DIA) || '/' || C.MES_ANO DIA,
      C.ANO_MES || CASE WHEN C.DIA < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END || TO_CHAR(C.DIA) DIA_REVERSO,
      C.MES_ANO,
      C.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
   FROM
      (
      SELECT
        B.DIA,
         A.MES_ANO,
         A.ANO_MES,
         A.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
      FROM
         (
            SELECT '04/2018' MES_ANO, '201804' ANO_MES, EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE('30/04/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')) ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '05/2018' MES_ANO, '201805' ANO_MES, EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE('31/05/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')) ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT '06/2018' MES_ANO, '201806' ANO_MES, EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE('30/06/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')) ULTIMO_DIA_MES FROM DUAL 
         ) A,
         ( SELECT ROWNUM DIA FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 31 ) B 
      WHERE
         B.DIA <= A.ULTIMO_DIA_MES
      ) C
   ) D
WHERE D.DIA_REVERSO < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
ORDER BY TO_DATE(D.DIA, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Parece que há um bug no Oracle que o faz aplicar a condição na cláusula WHERE exterior, nas subconsultas.

Comment: Ao usar o TRUNC(SYSDATE) o erro persiste. Quanto ao campo A.ULTIMO_DIA_MES ser número, mesmo que isso não esteja interferindo na ocorrência do erro ORA-01839, sim, no exemplo acima ele pode ser colocado apenas como número, mas o código completo que está em produção utiliza a function last_day do Oracle que já retorna o último dia do mês em formato date.

Comment: Editado. Consegui fazer funcionar, mas retirei todos os tipos DATE.

Comment: Marcelo, realmente este erro está parecendo um bug do Oracle mas foi possível contornar o problema usando essa solução que você sugeriu. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que formatação de data e hora do seu banco não esteja no mesmo padrão que esta tentando comparar.

Verifique a formatação de data e hora com o comando:

```
select sysdate from dual.
```

Se tiver diferente, (no exemplo meu banco esta em um formato diferente `06/21/2018 13:56:12`) do formato que esta tentando fazer a comparação faça a conversão, e depois a comparação:

```
select to_date('06/21/2018', 'MM/DD/RRRR') from dual;
```

No seu caso, seria algo como:

```
WHERE 
   D.DIA < to_date(sysdate, 'MM/DD/RRRR')
```

---

Se quiser trocar o formato de data na sua sessão para testar:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='MM/DD/RRRR hh24:mi:ss';
```

---

Se quiser trocar definitivamente no banco, acesse como DBA / SYS:

```
alter system set nls_date_format='MM/DD/RRRR hh24:mi:ss' scope=spfile;
```

ou da uma olhada nessa resposta [how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447608/how-to-change-default-nls-date-format-for-oracle-jdbc-client)

Comment: Substitui o "D.DIA < SYSDATE" por "D.DIA < TO_DATE('21/06/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')" e mesmo assim o erro persiste. Quanto a verificação da formatação de data e hora com "select sysdate from dual", ela não é o problema pois está retornando "22/06/2018 14:08:51" que é compatível com o formato do campo D.DIA